# Using a data service to centralize data and http calls in Angular

Tags: angular

I have read many Angular tutorials about how to implement http calls in services using the http client, thats fine. The problem comes when I try to separate the data and the http calls in two different services, I get confused because of the observables and subscriptions and in terms of architecture.

Please check the example below:

- 1 ListComponent - to show a list of items
- 1 DataService - for the data, with the item list and functions to get, add, update, delete, etc.
- 1 HttpService - for the http calls, generated automatically with Swagger for Angular.

I use the DataService as a central point for my data, so that it can be accessed from different components. When the ListComponent asks for the item list, the DataService calls the http service to fetch data from the server. This operation in the http service is asynchronous and so it returns a Observable.

I have implemented it using a Subject and Subscription:

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private listChangedSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.list = this.dataService.getList();
    this.listChangedSubscription = this.dataService.listChangedSubject.subscribe(
      (list: Array<Item>) => {
        this.list = list;
    });

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.entriesChangedSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

export class DataService {

  listChangedSubject = new Subject<Array<Item>>();

  private list: Array<Item> = [];

  private fetchItems() {
    return this.httpService.getItems().subscribe(
      (list: Array<Item>) => {
        this.list= list;
        this.listChangedSubject.next(this.list.slice());
      }
    );
  }

export class HttpService {

    public getItems(observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<Array<Item>>;
    public getItems(observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpResponse<Array<Item>>>;
    public getItems(observe?: 'events', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpEvent<Array<Item>>>;
    public getItems(observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false ): Observable<any> {
```

I think it could be a better approach using **Observables or Promises** in the DataService instead of the Subject and Subscription, but I don't get to make it work, any suggestions for the fetchData() function?

In all the tutorials I have read the components directly calls to the http service, which I think is only valid for simple scenarios in which the component holds its data and there is no need of a data service.

What would be the recommended approach for this?

Thanks in advance!

Dani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of years working in Angular, I think I can answer my own question :-)

> I think it could be a better approach using Observables or Promises in
> the DataService instead of the Subject and Subscription, but I don't
> get to make it work, any suggestions for the fetchData() function?

It is very common in Angular to use Subject in services, so you can emit values and clients can subscribe. For the later, usually a property or method is added like this:

```
const itemsSubject = new Subject<any>();

const items$ = itemsSubject.asObservable();
```

or

```
function getItems(): Observable<any> {
  return itemsSubject.asObservable();
}
```

For the particular case of a data service making http requests a BehaviourSubject or ReplaySubject can be used so that clients that subscribe after the request has completed can get the previous response.

> In all the tutorials I have read the components directly calls to the
> http service, which I think is only valid for simple scenarios in
> which the component holds its data and there is no need of a data
> service.
>
> What would be the recommended approach for this?

Angular components main purpose is to handle presentation of the view. As soon as fetching or processing data gets complicated, it is strongly recommended extracting it to a service. This allows for better component reusability and improves testability.

Take this as a general advice and make your choices depending on the case.

---

Here there is a list of posts that can be taken as reference:

https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/rxjs-subjects

https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93

Also I suggest reading the official docs of Angular and RxJS:

https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/

https://www.learnrxjs.io/

Answer (score 1):

Ahh okay, so I think I better understand, 
I think the best way to accomplish this still the dataService with Subjects. Really this is what RXJS does best.

List Component Template:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of list"> 
  <li (click)="onClick(item)"> 
    <span>{{ item.date } </span>
    <span>{{ item.text }}</span> 
  </li>
</ul>

export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  list: Item[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpService.getItems().subscribe(val => {
      this.list = val;
    });
  }

  onClick(item: item): void {
    this dataService.updateItemListSubject(item);
    // navigate to route
  } 
}
```

Notice you no longer need onDestroy and the subscription list. HttpClient will do that for you

```
export class DataService {

  private itemSubject = new Subject<Item>();

  getItemSubject(): Observable<Item> {
    return this.itemSubject.asObservable();
  }

  updateItemSubject(item: Observable<Item>): void {
    this.itemSubject.next(item);
  }

}
```

ItemDetail Component Template

```
<div>
  {{item$ | async}}
</div>

export class ItemDetail implements OnInit {
  item$: Observable<Item>

  ngOnInit() {
    this.item$ = this.dataService.getItemSubject();
  }
}

export class HttpService {
  // normal stuff
}
```

Sorry for this being so long.

Having the DataService make Http calls will likely get complicated somewhere down the road and requires the DataService know more about the application then it should. So that's why I make the Http calls in the parent component and then assign the response to a value in the DataService as shown above.

The advantage of using RXJS is that everywhere you use the data through the async pipe or by subscribing will get notified every time there is a change. It will also prevent you from having to worry about the scenario where you get the list from the DataService and accidentally do `list.splice(2)` and it breaks everything because you forgot that the list is being used everywhere.

Comment: I usually prefer having services that access to data rather than components, so it is easier to share data between them.

For instance, in this app the onClick(item) navigates to the detail of the item, passing the id of the item as a route param (:id). I need to get the item object for this id inside the ItemDetail component, so having the list in a service not a component makes it easier. I could implement it with @Input but it would be less elengat. Any advice on this?

Comment: Thanks Andrew fior your comment!

The list is used only for representation and selection:

`<ul *ngFor="let item of items"> <li (click)="onClick(item)"> <span>{{ item.date } </span> <span>{{ item.text }}</span> </li> </ul>`

Comment: I updated my answer to be more clear as to what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

It could be better and cleaner if you write own services and not use swagger or ... . You can create a generic service and call it on your model like Item and prevent using any to get power of typescript and intellisense. Below is an example:

service:

```
@Injectable()
export class GenericService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  get<T>(url: string): Observable<T> {
    return this._http.get<T>(url);
  }
  post<T,U>(url: string, body: U): Observable<T> {
    return this._http.post<T>(url, body);
  }
  put<T,U>(url: string, body: U): Observable<T> {
    return this._http.put<T>(url, body);
  }
  delete<T>(url: string): Observable<T> {
    return this._http.delete<T>(url);
  }
}
```

component

```
@Component({
  selector: ''
  ...
  providers: [GenericService]
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  list: Item[] = [];

  constructor(private _service: GenericService)

  ngOnInit() {
    this._service.get<Item>(url).subscribe(val => {
      this.list = val;
    }
  }
}
```

By using this approach you can remove your services files and where you need calling an api, inject the generic service to component and call your desired http method. you can convert Observable to promise by calling toPromise() on httpClient methods inside GenericService.